# Kafka Connect JDBC: Does it possble load banle in bulk mode, but only if any record in table changed?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have situtation when i need load dimension table to kafka.
Juts because i want expose all my application data through kafka, as common way over all company departments/products.

But my dimension is correct only as snaphsot, immpossible to process them in incremental mode. Because Kafka Stream i add "batch_id"(timestamp of load ops). I know that this is HACK, but it's work fine to me because i want stream only fact table which are very very big and also don't want have two different way to expose data. 
So no i have abillity process my dimensions as stream with logical window by "bacth_id".

But now I need load dimmesion by time interval (e g. 30 secs). My dimmesions add/update/delete rate is very low. Some of dimesions do not updated for a quaters.

So my question does it possible to use bulk mode with some condition.
For example only if any record in table have changed column "update_datetime? Does it possible mix bulk + timestamp mode?

Comment: You could externally schedule a topic deletion, or change topic retention based on the update interval, but bulk connector setting will always scan the whole table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cricket_007 explain in his comment, threre is no such functionaliy.
So threre are two way for resolve this issue.
Writec custom puller or write custom plugin got kafka-conenct.
I take in work first way. Because i use k8s, which are very comfortable for maintain a lot of different services. And separate service is much better to monitor.
But if you don;t have comfortable ingrastructure (with resource negotiation, service discovery, auotamted ci/cd etc) for microservices. I recomed write custom plugin to kafka-connect.